# The entity name must immediately follow the '&'

Tags: html, xml, spring-mvc, openshift, thymeleaf

I deploy my webapp on openshift (tomcat 7) and I have error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="null", line 2 - column 23 (dodaj:42)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 23; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

and the code for this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="HTML 5 CSS 3 Spring Form"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/> 
<script src="../../js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js" th:src="@{/js/libs/modernizr- 2.0.6.min.js}"></script>
</head>
............
<tr>
    <td width="100px"><b>CATEGORY:</b></td>
    <td width="400px">
      <select th:field="*{category.name}" >
(this is line 42)   <option th:each="c : ${category}" th:value="${c.name}" th:utext="${c.name}">

    </option>
    </select>

    </tr>
```

I searched solution but didn' find . On my localhost worked fine. Maybe someone had the similar problem. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what "dodaj" means, but the message says the error is in line 2.

Comment: It is my html name "dodaj.html". I think that line 2 (<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">) is correct (in others files works fine)

Comment: Hm. Can you look at the generated HTML source (in the browser) when you get the error? Or is the error message all you get?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The problem was in my db. In category names I have got for example "Education & Science" and thymeleaf had got the problem with "&" in`:

```
<option th:each="c : ${category}" th:value="${c.name}" th:utext="${c.name}">
```

I change it for "and" and everythings work.

Comment: Why you don't use `th:text` instead of `th:utext`? I would expected that it then works. Otherwise it looks like a bug for me.